# Local data mode in DJI Mobile SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

I understand that the local data mode is only available through the DJI Pilot app but will this option be made available through the Mobile SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Mobile SDK 4.4 added the [Local Data Mode](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/LDMManager/DJILDMManager.html) capability.